# Upload file from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, input, file-upload

Is it possible to successfully upload files that are passed as an Array of file objects via FormData?

Something like this:

```
var files_array = [];
$.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
  files_array.push(file);
});
```

Now if I push it to FormData:

```
formData.set('files', files_array);
```

It is not correctly received by Laravel backend.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it was to append files directly to FormData (surprisingly passing an array didn't work):

```
let i = 0;
fileList.forEach(function(file) {
  formData.append('image' + i, file);
  i++;
});
```

and then access them like this in Laravel controller:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_FILES); $i++) {
  if($request->hasFile('image' . $i)) $request->file('image' . $i)->store('photos/');
}
```